# How to run after successfull fetch in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```js
let users_data = [];
try {
  let users = await chatModel.find({ users: isVerified.userId });
  users.forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.users.forEach(async function (user) {
      if (isVerified.userId !== user) {
        let result = await userModel.find({ _id: user }, { firstName: 1 });
        users_data.push({ id: user, name: result[0].firstName });
      }
      console.log("Users_data from try =>", users_data);
    });
  });

  console.log("Users data => ", users_data);
  res.render("chat-app", { users: users_data });
} catch (error) {
  users_data = "";
  console.log(error);
  console.log("Users data => ", users_data);
  res.render("chat-app", { users: users_data });
}
```

In the above code i want to log and render page once all data is fetched how can i achieve this here

Comment: Push your promises to an array, then `Promise.all` them.

Comment: By not using `forEach` with async functions, but by `map` inside a Promise.all.

Comment: can you please give by example

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store all the promises in a variable. Then, wait for all of them before calling `res.render`. Since you are looping through a nested array, I used [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) in the answer.

```js
let users_data = [];
try {
  const users = await chatModel.find({ users: isVerified.userId });
  const promises = users.flatMap(function (doc) {
    return doc.users.map(async function (user) {
      if (isVerified.userId !== user) {
        let result = await userModel.find({ _id: user }, { firstName: 1 });
        users_data.push({ id: user, name: result[0].firstName });
      }
      console.log("Users_data from try =>", users_data);
    });
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log("Users data => ", users_data);
  res.render("chat-app", { users: users_data });
} catch (error) {
  users_data = "";
  console.log(error);
  console.log("Users data => ", users_data);
  res.render("chat-app", { users: users_data });
}
```